# Add dynamic number of columns in grid according to query in BIRT

Tags: mysql, birt

i have a query which designs dynamic number of columns from a table having data.
now i need to add grid with dynamic number of columns according to query.

`select fruit,count(*) from mytable group by fruit;`

i am getting how to add it manually but at runtime i may be having  different number of columns. so what procedure i need to do for adding columns to grid dynamically in BIRT report

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/217283/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend or modify your report template at runtime in, for instance, a custom EventHandler for the Report.beforeFactory() event. The handler can be implemented either in Java or in JavaScript. BIRT has [Design Engine API](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/designEngineAPI.php). There is a [plug-in](https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-dynamic-columns/wiki/Home), that could be helpful. Even if you cannot use it as it is, it provides examples of how to use BIRT Design Engine API. Using Design Enigine API you can also create new template from scratch at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Crosstab and have `fruits` as a *Dimension and* `COUNT(*)` as a *Measure*. It will add a column for each fruit, but it might be an overkill for your example.